# How to access URL segment(s) in blade in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a url : `http://localhost:8888/projects/oop/2`

I want to access the first segment --> `projects`

I've tried

`<?php echo $segment1 =  Request::segment(1);  ?>`

I see nothing print out in my view when I refresh my page.

---

Any helps / suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: did you use Request namaspace?

Comment: Yes. Should I declare it somewhere ? How do I do that ?

Comment: @ImtiazPabel : Should I include this on the top `use Request;`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try this

```
{{ Request::segment(1) }}
```

Comment: How is it diff than what I have ? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @ihue it's not. Blade will internally convert "{{" into "<?php echo" and "}}" into ";?>". So it's exactly the same as what you are doing, and will work just the same.

Answer (score 13):

**BASED ON LARAVEL 5.7 & ABOVE**

To get all segments of current URL:

`$current_uri = request()->segments();`

To get segment `posts` from http://example.com/users/posts/latest/

**NOTE:** Segments are an array that starts at index 0. The first element of array starts after the TLD part of the url. So in the above url, segment(0) will be `users` and segment(1) will be `posts`.

```
//get segment 0
$segment_users = request()->segment(0); //returns 'users'
//get segment 1
$segment_posts = request()->segment(1); //returns 'posts'
```

You may have noted that the segment method only works with the current URL ( `url()->current()` ). So I designed a method to work with previous URL too by cloning the `segment()` method:

```
public function index()
{
    $prev_uri_segments = $this->prev_segments(url()->previous());
}

 /**
 * Get all of the segments for the previous uri.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function prev_segments($uri)
{
    $segments = explode('/', str_replace(''.url('').'', '', $uri));

    return array_values(array_filter($segments, function ($value) {
        return $value !== '';
    }));
}
```

Comment: This is not true (at least not anymore for Laravel 8.47)! `segments()` returns a 0-based array, but if you call `segment()` the indexing is 1-based, so `segment(1)` will be "users" and `segment(2)` will be "posts". In typical Laravel style, this is not mentioned *at all* in the documentation, but the doc comment  of the `segment()` method "Get a segment from the URI (1 based index)." confirms this.

Answer (score 11):

The double curly brackets are processed via Blade -- not just plain PHP. This syntax basically echos the calculated value.

```
{{ Request::segment(1) }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is how one can do it via the global `request` helper function.

`{{ request()->segment(1) }}`

**Note:** `request()` returns the object of the `Request` class.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to get the first or last segment, in case you are unsure of the path length.

```
$segments = request()->segments();
$last  = end($segments);
$first = reset($segments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code you can get  url segment.

```
{{ Request::segment(1) }}
```

If you don't want the data to be escaped then use {!! !!} else use {{ }}.

```
{!! Request::segment(1) !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests

Comment: Can you give an example of when you would want to use the not escaped version? Also, be very careful with this! It is very easy for users with malicious intent to play with the url if you do.