# How to fetch values from URL in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have well researched and found that this question is unique.
I am newbie to Laravel, 
I am sending link in email for forget password while in link there are 3 parameters email,id and time all encoded.
Now When user click on that link further operations will begin.
Now I am stuck at how to get all values from URL.

Here is my Link Code:

```
$url = $baseurl . "/changepwd/" . $id_enc . "/" . $email_enc . "/" . $time;
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/changepwd/{$id}/{$email}/{$time}', 'UserController@change_password_web');
```

When user clicks on link that function:

```
public function change_password_web($id ,$email, $time)
    {
        echo $request->route('id');
    }
```

My Url says:

```
http://localhost/laravelproject/changepwd/MQ==/amF5bWluemFwQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==/1504772185
```

When I try this error says

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>   NotFoundHttpException

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't like that it's in a sub folder and expects URLs like `http://localhost/changepwd/MQ==/amF5bWluemFwQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==/1504772185`

Comment: No its not in subfolder

Comment: As I try without passing arguements in url, it works

Comment: Please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832819/how-to-access-url-segments-in-blade-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @RahulMeshram I need it in controller not in vuiew, Can i use it still?

Comment: have you tried ?

Comment: Yes I have tried indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove $ sign in the route:

```
Route::get('/changepwd/{id}/{email}/{time}', 'UserController@change_password_web');
```

Or you can use route without params and check them in the controller's method:

```
public function change_password_web()
{
    $id = request('id');
    $email = request('email');
    $time = request('time');
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks but I have a doubt, its like everytime if I want to pass in URL, I have to do with this similar pattern or is there any other way also?

Comment: Sure, you can also use route without pattern. And then check request parameters with `$myVar = request('myVar')`

Comment: Can you add in the answer  as "OR you can try like this" Will be helpful :) Thanks